# How to access graph API in Azure AD v2.0 for shared mailbox?

Tags: email, azure, authorization, openid

I need to write an app that will read messages in several shared mailboxes.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/myaccount@mydomain.com/messages
```

This request is sent with the authorization token.
Works perfectly for me. The shared mailbox belongs to me as well. However:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/sharedmailbox@mydomain.com/messages
```

Always return 403 Unauthorized. Is it even possible? If not, what are the alternatives?